# DOM Exception 18 in Awesomium

Tags: angularjs, awesomium

I have a webpage being loaded from the local file system and rendered using [awesomium](http://awesomium.com/), the page is using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/#/list)to render part of the page. However, I have a problem with part of my AngularJS controller generating a Dom Exception 18:

> angular-1.0.0rc10.js @ line 5349 Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

It seems this exception is caused by the presence of this code at the end of my AngularJS controller:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://placeholdermetaserver.appspot.com/list?format=json&game=Heist'})
.success(function(data)
{
    //Do stuff with data
});
```

Oddly enough everything is just fine if I use a straight XMLHttpRequest instead of the AngularJS $http object:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function() {
    //Do stuff with data
};
request.open("GET", "http://placeholdermetaserver.appspot.com/list?format=json&game=Heist", true);
```

This exception is *not* generated when I simply load this page in chrome (off the local file system, same as awesomium).

What could cause this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The `$http` service includes some Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) countermeasures. I'm not especially familiar with Awesomium, so I'm not sure what security features it implements, but I'd consult the documentation (both of Awesomium and AngularJS) for more info.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module.ng.$http

From the perspective of your server, this is prone to the [textbook XSRF img tag attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Example_and_characteristics) if you ever send a GET request like:

> "http://myapp.com/doSomething/somegame/12345"

From the perspective of your client, let's say you make a request like:

> "http://myapp.com/doSomething/somegame/" + someId

A clever hacker might coax someId to be:

> ```
> "@123.45.56.689/myEvilFakeJson.json"
> ```

In which case the request isn't made to your server, but instead some
other one. If you hard code the location of the request or are careful with sanitizing input, it probably won't be that much of a risk.

Comment: Ah, from those docs it looks like $http shouldn't ever work, in awesomium or chrome, for what I'm trying to do? Awesomium has an option to completely disable the same origin policy, which I'm running with, other than that I can't find any specific security measures mentioned in the docs that ought to affect this.

Comment: @Martin Yeah, that may be the case. Although I hate to suggest it (as it may be less secure), your best bet might be to use XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: In what ways may it be less secure?

Comment: Aha, I'm not vulnerable to that because the request is fetching from a completely hardcoded location, so there's no chance that can be changed.